# Docking G2 to ubuntu for syncing and running apps

Tags: kernel

Hey guys I would like to dock my phone with ubuntu and run everything from thie.
However I don't have the docking station and would like to know if I can use the usb since I don't have the docking stationto sync and run the apps and stuff like that from my phone to pc since I've herd they share same kernel

Answer (score 0):

You're probably referring to Ubuntu for Android. That's not yet available.

Comment: I can already run it on my device my question is how can I sync it to the pc so that I can run the applications from thier